# Two Numpy arrays form a matrix in Python/Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, grid-layout

I have three numpy arrays and I want to get a matrix for different combination `([np1,np2],[np2,np3],[np1,np3])`. The specific for the element of the matrix is average of each `X` and `Y` value and then plus a constant value. For example,

```
[np1,np2], constant  = 2
```

`np1 = np.array([1,2,3])`
`np2 = np.array([4,5,6])`
`np3 = np.array([7,8,9])`

[OUTPUT LOOKS LIKE THIS][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWpek.png

UPDATED INFO : These three arrays are existing ones.

Output looks like this for example [np1,np2]

```
np2/np1  1            2     3
         ____________________
    4 |  [(1+4)/2+2]  5     5.5
    5 |  5            5.5   6
    6 |  5.5          6     6.5
```

Comment: I’m a bit confused by the (lack of) question.  Are you asking how to generate the arrays, or how to combine the *existing* arrays into a matrix?  Additionally, please convert the image to *text*, as we cannot copy/paste data from an image.

Comment: Is `np.array([np1+np2, np2+np3, np1+np3])/2 + constant` sufficient to answer your question?